# Mirror an Excel sheet but with a control column that does not come from it

Tags: excel, mirroring

I will be trying to mirror an Excel sheet into another one. But what I also need to do is to add a column to this mirrored sheet to check whether this row has been processed before or not. The reason for this is, that I cannot alter the main sheet because a survey tool keeps sending the new answers to this sheet and it simply stops updating when we change it.

The control column can be something like `IsRowProcessed` with a value of 0 or 1. But this value should exist independently of the main sheet.

To make things easier, each row on the main sheet contains a column that holds a unique token value. We can call this column `Token`.

I wonder if this is possible?

Comment: Please detail what you mean by "this row has been processed before or not"

Comment: @ThomasC. Of course. The mirrored sheet should be traversed by an external system that uses this flag to check whether it should read this row or not. The external system is, unfortunately, very limited in fetching rows. It can only fetch a limited number of rows, so when we read a row that is not processed and read it into this system, we then mark it as `IsRowProcessed=1`. Next time the system reads the sheet, it only picks up X number of other rows with `IsRowProcessed=0` instead of checking all the rows.

Comment: my first idea, if you're using Office 365, is to use [UNIQUE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e) formula to reference `Token` column and then use [XLookUp](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) formulas to retrieve other columns. I am not so sure it will fit your needs because of the control column

Comment: @ThomasC. I'm afraid I need a more descriptive answer.

Comment: Sorry, I only wanted to point out formulas that might help you. IMO its difficult to achieve what you want without VBA because of the system that process the rows

Comment: @ThomasC. Thank you! As you say, the problem is getting unnecessarily complex, and it's all due to MS Power Automate's limitations. I have started playing with MS Azure Functions instead. But if you came up with a solution, please let me know.